How to check the naturality in Hartshorne exercise II.2.4
Hartshorne exercise II.2.4 is the following:

Let $A$ be a ring and let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a scheme. Given a morphism $f : X \to \operatorname{Spec} A$, we have an associated map on sheaves $f^\# : \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \to f_* \mathcal{O}_X$. Taking global sections we obtain a homomorphism $A \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$. Thus there is a natural map $$\alpha : \operatorname{Hom}_{Sch}(X, \operatorname{Spec} A) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{Rings}(A, \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X).$$ Show that $\alpha$ is bijective.

My understanding is that the "naturality" of this bijection is important to prove that $\operatorname{Spec}$ and $\Gamma$ are adjoint functors, but I am still learning the generalities of adjoint pairs. So what are the commutative diagrams that I need to check for naturality to see that $\operatorname{Spec}$ and $\Gamma$ are adjoint?

The diagrams are as follows: for a given map $g\colon Y\to X$ of schemes, with the map $g^\sharp\colon\mathcal{O}_X\to g_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ on structure sheaves, we need to show that the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Hom}_{Sch}(X,\mathrm{Spec}\,A) @>{\alpha_{X,A}}>>\mathrm{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))\\
@V{-\circ g}VV @VV{g^\sharp(X)\circ-}V\\
\mathrm{Hom}_{Sch}(Y,\mathrm{Spec}\,A) @>{\alpha_{Y,A}}>>\mathrm{Hom}(A,\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y))
\end{CD}
$$
commutes; for a given map $\psi\colon A\to B$ of rings, we need to show that the square
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Hom}_{Sch}(X,\mathrm{Spec}\,A) @>{\alpha_{X,A}}>>\mathrm{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))\\
@A{\mathrm{Spec}\,\psi\circ-}AA @AA{-\circ\psi}A\\
\mathrm{Hom}_{Sch}(X,\mathrm{Spec}\,B) @>{\alpha_{X,B}}>>\mathrm{Hom}(B,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))\\
\end{CD}$$
These diagrams follow from how the functoriality of $\mathrm{Spec}$, $\Gamma(-,\mathcal{O}_-)$ and the hom-functors are defined.

Thank you! I will have to sit down and explicitly write out the checks that these commute, but I really appreciate you taking the time to type up the squares themselves!

Just looking at this more closely - is something off in the second diagram? $\operatorname{Spec}$ is contravariant, so should the vertical arrows on both sides be going in the opposite direction?

Yes, sorry, I drew the arrows in the wrong direction.
